# Chaining javascript functions. What's the order of execution?

Tags: javascript

aka if I have a function `var nameNorm= name.substring(1).toLowerCase();`

what would the order be? would it turn everything lowercase then extract a substring or would it extract a substring and then turn the substring lowercase?

Comment: This really has nothing at all to do with prototypes, at least in any direct way. It's about the syntactic binding of operators in the expression grammar.

Answer (score 11):

The `.` operator associates left-to-right.

so you would do the substring first, then the lower case.

Comment: can we decide about the order in `name()`, in case we want to receive same result with any order?

Comment: @AriShojaei: I'm afraid I don't understand the question.  `name` here is not a function.

Answer (score 8):

It executes from left to right.  So `substring(1)` executes, then `toLowerCase()` executes on the resulting substring.